# Arduino Switching Between Loops IR Remote

Tags: adafruit, ir, remote-control, neopixel, loop

I've been working on an LED strip project. However, I've come to a stand still at the moment. Within the program I am wanting to assign different lighting effects to each button on my IR remote. I am wanting the program to work on the basis that each lighting effect will run, until another button is pressed, to start another effect.

Currently with my code I have made it so each effect will run, once, when the corresponding button on the IR remote is pressed.

I am fairly new to C++ / Arduino but from my understanding I need to have a variable which would hold the current value of the IR remote. I am unsure on how to actually implement this. I will post my code below and if anyone could give me tips or even amendments to my code it would be to a great help.

Thank you in advanced.

```cpp
#include "IRremote.h"
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#ifdef __AVR__
#include <avr/power.h>
#endif
#define PIN 6

Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(20, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

int receiver = 11; // Signal Pin of IR receiver to Arduino Digital Pin 11

/*-----( Declare objects )-----*/
IRrecv irrecv(receiver);     // create instance of 'irrecv'
decode_results results;      // create instance of 'decode_results'
int Remote = 0;

/*-----( Function )-----*/
void translateIR() // takes action based on IR code received

// describing Remote IR codes 

{
  switch(results.value)
  {
  case 0xFFA25D: Serial.println("POWER"); 
  ArrowRight(strip.Color(25, 0, 0), 100); //Red
  ArrowRight(strip.Color(0, 0, 25), 100); //Blue
  break;

  case 0xFFE21D: Serial.println("FUNC/STOP"); 
  ArrowLeft(strip.Color(25, 0, 0), 100); // Red
  ArrowLeft(strip.Color(0, 0, 25), 100); // Blue
  break;


  default: 
  Serial.println(" other button   ");

  }// End Case

  delay(0); // Do not get immediate repeat


} //END translateIR
void setup()   /*----( SETUP: RUNS ONCE )----*/
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("IR Receiver Button Decode"); 
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
  strip.begin();
  strip.show();
  Remote = 0;

}/*--(end setup )---*/


void loop()   /*----( LOOP: RUNS CONSTANTLY )----*/
{
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) // have we received an IR signal?

  {
    translateIR(); 
    irrecv.resume(); // receive the next value
  }  
}/* --(end main loop )-- */

void ArrowRight(uint32_t c, uint8_t wait) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) { // The j<# determines how many cycles
    for (uint16_t i = strip.numPixels()/2; i < strip.numPixels(); i++) {
      strip.setPixelColor(i, c);
      strip.show();
      delay(50);
    }
    for (uint16_t i = 0; i < strip.numPixels(); i++) {
      strip.setPixelColor(i, 0);
    }
    strip.show();
    delay(50);
  }
}

void ArrowLeft(uint32_t c, uint8_t wait) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) { // The j<# determines how many cycles
    for (uint16_t i = strip.numPixels()/2-1; i + 1 > 0 ; i--) {
      strip.setPixelColor(i, c);
      strip.show();
      delay(50);
    }
    for (uint16_t i = strip.numPixels(); i + 1 > 0 ; i--) {
      strip.setPixelColor(i, 0);
    }
    strip.show();
    delay(50);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`delay(0)` apparently[*] acts like `delay(2^32)` or about 10^10 milliseconds. That may not be what you had in mind ... :)

Try reducing the delay to 1 or use `delayMicroseconds()` to get something shorter. That should at least get you some repeatable results.

(10^10 mSec is ~ 16.5 weeks, for those without a calculator handy).

[*]  I didn't read the code, nor wait for the call to expire. I tried it and saw that the Uno froze. I'm guessing a zero-argument to delay() isn't rejected but just gets decremented as usual, until it hits zero.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I'm not sure you've understood what I'm wanting to achieve. I am wanting each effect to continuously loop until another button is pressed, activating another effect. I've loaded the code I pasted onto my uno, it works fine for me. I did changed the delay like you said, this seems to just change the speed of which my effect happens, changing it to 1 makes the effect turn into a flash. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to have a variable which would hold the current value of the
>   IR remote.

You already have one.  It's called results and is of type decode_results.

```
decode_results results;
```

You read the IR results into that variable.  Then you clear it to look for another one.  What you need is a way to store the last good code that you got.  Your best bet is to just use an int and store a certain number for each code, store a 1 when you get 0xFFA25D and a 2 when you get 0xFFE21D or something like that.  Then use that int instead of the results variable to decide what to do in the rest of the code.